# Perform KS-test on Random Number Generator

Tags: beginner, functional-programming, scala

I've just started practicing Functional Programming in Scala in some days. This is the code I used to perform KS-test on a random number generator.

```
class RNG {
    def next(): Double;
}

import scala.math.sqrt;
object main {
  val length: Int = 100000;
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // generate 100000 random numbers
    var seed: Array[Long] = Array.range(1, 7).map(x => x.toLong);
    var gen: RNG = new RNG(seed);
    var data: Array[Double] = (new Array[Double](length)).map {case (x) => gen.next()};

    // sort data
    val sorted = data.sortWith((x, y) => x < y);

    // perform ks test
    val baseline: Array[Int] = Array.range(0, length);
    val baselinemin: Array[Double] = baseline.map {case (x) => x.toDouble/length}
    val baselinemax: Array[Double] = baseline.map {case (x) => (1+x.toDouble)/length}

    val diffmin = (sorted.zip(baselinemin)).map {case (x, y) => x - y};
    val diffmax = (sorted.zip(baselinemax)).map {case (x, y) => y - x};

    val max1 = diffmin.max;
    val max2 = diffmax.max;

    val d = if (max1 > max2) max1 else max2;
    println("D\t" + d);
    val dbase = 2/sqrt(length);
    println("D base\t" + dbase);
  }
}
```

There is a little weird thing that in line

```
var data: Array[Double] = (new Array[Double](length)).map {case (x) => gen.next()};
```

Question:

- if I remove new, the program returns a wrong answer.
- Is there any way to make this code looks more professional?

Thanks!

Comment: Please be more specific in what you are looking for in a review. What do you mean with "looks more professional?". Also, do you understand what is happening with that `map` function? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This isn't a question: "*if I remove new, the program returns a wrong answer.*" That's a statement (and probably means you shouldn't remove `new`).

Comment: @TobySpeight I think it should be some kind of error comes out due to undefined behavior, right?

Comment: @dfhwze I'm practicing Scala, It should be some kinda standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The code, as posted, does not compile.
- All the semicolons `;` can be removed. You almost never see them in idiomatic Scala.
- Unnecessary use of `var`. Use `val`.
- Replace `Array.range(1, 7).map(x => x.toLong)` with `Array.iterate(1L, 7)(_+1)`.
- Replace `case (x)` with underscore `_` when `x` is unused.
- Replace `case (x) => x` with underscore `_` when `x` is used immediately and once.
- `data.sortWith((x, y) => x < y)` same thing as `data.sorted`.
- Variable `data` not needed: `val sorted : Array[Double] = Array.fill(length)(gen.next()).sorted`
- Unnecessary parentheses when defining `diffmin` and `diffmax`.
- Variables `max1` and `max2` not needed: `val d = diffmin.max max diffmax.max`

Comment: @jwvh I would refrain from answering on code that does not compile.